# EnvironmentNotWritableError in Conda

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, conda

I am trying to run this command `conda install pytorch torchvision cuda80 -c soumith`
 from this link `https://github.com/kenshohara/video-classification-3d-cnn-pytorch` and I am getting error as below. I don't have root privileges. Can anyone tell me what I should do to fix this issue?

```
    EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment.
  environment location: /usr/local/anaconda-2019.07
  uid: 3792
  gid: 1556
```

Comment: You can try `sudo chown 3792:1556 "/usr/local/anaconda-2019.07"`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a shared Anaconda then you should create your own local environments for your projects. E.g.,

```
conda create --name my_env -c pytorch torchvision
```

Also note that `pytorch` is the official channel from which to get PyTorch and that `torchvision` has a PyTorch and a CUDA requirement. Since you are in a shared environment, you may need to set local writable folders for downloading packages and storing your envs. For this, please read the Conda help:

```
conda config --describe envs_dirs pkgs_dirs
```

which can be set like,

```
conda config --add envs_dirs ~/my_envs
```

for example.

Generally, best practice is to create new envs on a per-project or per-project-type basis and try to avoid manipulating them once you've hardened the project requirements.